# Haskell: List comprehension of Glade entries

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, glade

I want to make an `entries :: Map(String -> Entry)` so I can easily access each entry by name.  To this end, I have the code

```
  Just xml ←  xmlNew "blah.glade"
  ...
  entries ← fromList $ [(name,entry) | name <- entryList 
      , entry <- xmlGetWidget xml castToEntry name]
```

(where `entryList` is a list of entry names, e.g. `["name1","name2",...]`).

However, the list comprehension comes up with the following error:

```
   Couldn't match expected type `[t]' against inferred type `IO Entry'
    In the expression: xmlGetWidget xml castToEntry name
    In a stmt of a list comprehension:
        entry <- xmlGetWidget xml castToEntry name
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
        `[(name, entry) |
              name <- entryList, entry <- xmlGetWidget xml castToEntry name]'
```

I can't see why it's expecting a list of anything.  Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `<-` in a list comprehension expects the right hand side to be a list. You're trying to use it to bind the result of an `IO` action, but that's only valid in `do` notation (without extensions, at least).

The problem is that `xmlGetWidget` returns `IO Entry`, but you want a map of `Entry`. That means you'll have to compose those `IO` actions into a larger one.

In the end, you'll want something like this:

```
let getEntry name = do entry <- xmlGetWidget xml castToEntry name
                       return (name, entry)
entries <- fromList <$> mapM getEntry entryList
```

Here, I've created a helper function `getEntry :: String -> IO (String, Entry)` to get the entry and pair it up with its name.

Next, I use `mapM` to map `getEntry` over the list of names. Note the difference between `map` and `mapM`. If I had used `map`, I would have gotten a list of actions, i.e. `[IO (String, Entry)]`, when what I want is an action returning a list, i.e. `IO [(String, Entry)]`.

Now, having constructed that `IO` action, I convert it to a `Map` using `fromList` with the operator `<$>`. Also known as `fmap`, `<$>` applies a pure function to the thing inside the `IO`, so the result is of type `IO (Map String Entry)`.

Finally, the result of this `IO` action can be bound to `entries`.

Comment: For some reason, my ghc doesn't recognize `<$>`, but I was able to do 

`entries ←  fromList \`fmap\` mapM getEntryTuple entryList`

instead.  Thanks for the description!

Comment: `<$>` is in `Control.Applicative`.